# Managed Code custom action in .Net Core 6 or later

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield

I have been using .Net framework managed code custom actions using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller and WiX references in Installshield tool. Is it possible to write managed code custom actions in .Net core 6 or later using Wix 4.0.3 or any other way?

I understand that windows-installer can't run in platform independent way but to migrate the whole project in .Net Core.

I had tried to create class library project using .Net 6. However, I am getting compilation errors same as below post:

[Wix4 C# CustomAction project compile error - WixToolset.Dtf.WindowsInstaller reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440520/wix4-c-sharp-customaction-project-compile-error-wixtoolset-dtf-windowsinstalle)

Comment: We always recommended Wix DTF to Advanced Installer users that wanted to build .NET custom actions but the lack of .Net Core support forced us to create our own support for developing custom actions. More and more users were asking so we decided to extend our VS extension with the following templates (limited only to Advanced Installer users): https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/create-dot-net-ca.html

Disclaimer: I work on the Advanced Installer team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not supported yet.

But we are looking at implementing something in [HeatWave](https://www.firegiant.com/docs/heatwave/) to support .NET Core CAs.

Comment: Can we use powershell core? I mean if we can get the session object, this might work..right?

Comment: "if we can get the session object..." is doing a lot of work in that question. :)